# How to get exact list of collections form mongo database in shell script

Tags: linux, mongodb, shell, sh

I would like to get the collection names list from mongo database.
So, I use the following command in shell script :

collections=`mongo $dbName --eval "db.getCollectionNames()"`

The output result of this command is

"MongoDB shell version: 2.2.0 connecting to: cm_v2 col1,col2,col3,col4"

I would like to get only the collections name such as : col,col2,col3,col4.
So, how should I delete the output like version from result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use [`--quiet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/parameters/#param.quiet)  flag

```
collections=mongo $dbName --quiet --eval "db.getCollectionNames()"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get an array of collections that you can iterate over use something like this (this might bite you if you have spaces in collection names though):

```
collections=`echo "show collections" | mongo $dbName --quiet`


for collection in $collections;
do 
    echo "$collection"
done
```

---

This will return a JSON formatted list of names with quotes, which is not really useful for BASH script

```
mongo $dbName --quiet --eval "db.getCollectionNames()"

[
    "collection1",
    "collection2"
]
```

Answer (score 2):

use below:

```
DATABASE_COLLECTIONS=$(mongo $dbName --quiet --eval "db.getCollectionNames().join('')" | sed 's/,/ /g')
```

Then you can

```
for col in $DATABASE_COLLECTIONS; do
    echo $col
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Batch version of **Davor Lucic**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38263342/4424236):

```
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%c in (
  `echo show collections ^| mongo "host:port/dbname" --quiet`
) do (
  echo %%c
)
```