# MongoDB dump all collections in a database with query

Tags: mongodb, dump

I want to dump data in mongodb with a specific time range.
Dump one collection works right.

```
mongodump --db VnTrader_Tick_ALL_1106 --collection au1712 --out tick_1106 --query "{ datetime: {$gte: new Date(1509973200000), $lt: new Date(1510038900000) }}"
```

And I am wondering how can I dump all collections in my database by same query?
Thanks a lot

Comment: `--query` is not allowed without specifying a collection. You would need to iterate the list of collections instead.

Comment: Thanks Neil, how can I iterate over collections with dump command? In mongo shell, there is a db.getCollectionNames().forEach. But how can I use this in cmd window? thanks

Comment: [How to get exact list of collections form mongo database in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21038710/2313887)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I work on windows platform and cannot run the command in the link you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem with a navie implementation.

1. first generate a dumpcommond.txt file in python with regular expression.

   command_tick = 'mongodump' + ' --db ' + HOST_TICK_DB + ' --collection ' + contract + ' --out tick_remote_1 ' + \
         ' --query "{ datetime: {$gte: new Date(' + ds_time + '), $lt: new Date(' + de_time + ')}}"'
   with open(MONGODB_BIN_PATH + '\dumpcommond.txt','a') as myfile:
        myfile.write(command_tick + '\n')
2. open a cmd in mongo/bin
3. copy and past all the commands in dumpcommond.txt the cmd to get all collections

Answer (score 0):

I don't have answer for this in Windows version. But I too crossed this scenario and used the following command in linux to achieve today with the help of xargs.

```
echo "show collections" | mongo <dbname> --quiet | grep -v "system.indexes" | xargs -I {} mongodump --db <dbname> --collection {} --query "{}"
```